# Migrating Docker Compose to Kubernetes Volume Mount Isn't Supported

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I am trying to change my existing deployment logic/switch to kubernetes (My server is in gcp and till now I used docker-compose to run my server.) So I decided to start by using `kompose` and generating services/deployments using my existing docker-compose file. After running

```
kompose --file docker-compose.yml convert

#I got warnings indicating  Volume mount on the host "mypath" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
```

After a little research I decided to use the command below to "fix" the issue

```
kompose convert --volumes hostPath
```

And what this command achieved is -> It replaced the persistent volume claims that were generated with the first command to the code below.

```
  volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /path
          name: certbot-hostpath0
        - mountPath: /somepath
          name: certbot-hostpath1
        - mountPath: /someotherpath
          name: certbot-hostpath2

- hostPath:
          path: /path/certbot
        name: certbot-hostpath0
      - hostPath:
          path: /path/cert_challenge
        name: certbot-hostpath1
      - hostPath:
          path: /path/certs
        name: certbot-hostpath2
```

But since I am working in my local machine

```
kubectl apply -f <output file>
```

results in The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
I didn't want to connect my local env with gcp just to generate the necessary files, is this a must? Or can I move this to startup-gcp etc

I feel like I am in the right direction but I need a confirmation that I am not messing something up.

1)I have only one compute engine(VM instance) and lots of data in my prod db. "How do I"/"do I need to" make sure I don't lose any data in db by doing something?
2)In startup-gcp  after doing everything else (pruning docker images etc) I had a docker run command that makes use of `docker/compose 1.13.0 up -d`. How should I change it to switch to kubernetes?
3)Should I change anything in  `nginx.conf`  as it referenced to 2 different services in my docker-compose (I don't think I should since same services also exist in kubernetes generated yamls)

Comment: I'd suggest reading through the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/) (there is a lot of it) and directly write Deployment YAML files and similar artifacts, rather than trying to convert your Docker setup.  For most applications you really shouldn't use `hostPath` volumes, especially if you're running in a cloud environment.

Comment: do you have kubernetes installed? yesterday another guy downloaded kubectl and though that's all you need to use kuberentes. You have to configure a cluster.

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand but my question is mostly about having access to same data in my db and lack of info in docs (at least to my beginner eyes) to achieve it. I already modified some of the yaml files but since my docker-compose file was really big, I thought it would be a better approach to generate them with kompose first

Comment: So I have no idea what will happen when I stop using host paths (and replace them with persistent-volume claims) I need some kind of insurance/methodology that would ensure me that I will still have access to same data I had in my compute instance VM/ my certificates keep renewing themselves etc

Comment: @suren Thanks for trying to help but I don't see how another guy downloading kubectl is related to this. My question  may be a trivial one to kubernetes experts but to me it is not clear at all by reading the docs what approach to take to make sure I still have all my data/operations intact after I create a new cluster/migrate to kubernetes.

Comment: You will have to migrate your data somehow.  If you're changing from a single-host Docker setup to a multi-host Kubernetes setup you probably won't be able to import the same physical database backing content; doing something like backing up your current database and restoring it into the cluster might make sense.  It's also very reasonable to run databases outside of Kubernetes paired with stateless replicated applications in the cluster, and this could be a path forward for you.

Comment: Thanks this is much more helpful. So from what I understand I should act like I am deploying a project from scratch instead of trying to find shortcuts to migrate to kubernetes. Would you suggest using the persistent disk claims instead of the host path? Also you can clarify/write your thoughts  an answer since it answers my question if I need to do everything from scratch and backup/restore the dp in the new cluster (ignoring the existing vm in compute engine).

Comment: Also (why) does running Kompose to convert my Docker setup hurt?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using Persistent Volume Claims (PVCs). If your cluster is managed, in most cases it can automatically create the PersistentVolumes for you.

One way to create the Persistent Volume Claims corresponding to your docker compose files is using Move2Kube(https://github.com/konveyor/move2kube). You can download the release and place it in path and run :

```
move2kube translate -s <path to your docker compose files>
```

It will then interactively allow you configure PVCs.

If you had a specific cluster you are targeting, you can get the specific storage classes supported by that cluster using the below command in a terminal where you have set your kubernetes cluster as context for kubectl.

```
move2kube collect
```

Once you do collect, you will have a m2k_collect folder, which you can then place it in the folder where your docker compose files are. And when you run move2kube translate it will automatically ask you whether to target this specific cluster, and also option to choose the storage class from that cluster.

> 1)I have only one compute engine(VM instance) and lots of data in my
> prod db. "How do I"/"do I need to" make sure I don't lose any data in
> db by doing something?

Once the PVC is provisioned you can copy the data to the PVC by using kubectl cp command into a pod where the pvc is mounted.

> 2)In startup-gcp after doing everything else (pruning docker images
> etc) I had a docker run command that makes use of docker/compose
> 1.13.0 up -d. How should I change it to switch to kubernetes?

You can potentially change it to use helm chart. Move2Kube, during the interactive session, can help you create helm chart too. Once you have the helm chart, all you have to do is "helm upgrade -i

> 3)Should I change anything in nginx.conf as it referenced to 2
> different services in my docker-compose (I don't think I should since
> same services also exist in kubernetes generated yamls)

If the services names are name in most cases it should work.